# should changing the parent of a listbox change the selected index?

Tags: vb.net, listbox, selectedindex

You wouldn’t think so, but it does when the listbox is bound to a datasource (as far as I can see).

I’ve reduced the behaviour to the code below. The "if" line toggles between loading a list via data binding and loading a list “manually” (both use the same data table). In each case I set the selected index afterwards, and then change the parent form. With manual loading, the selected index is retained, with binding it is lost. I cannot see how this makes any sense – I don't see why changing the host form should alter any property of the list. Is this a bug?

```
Public Class Form1
    Sub main() Handles Me.Load
        Dim ListControl1 As ListBox = New ListBox
        ListControl1.Parent = Me
        Dim dt = New DataTable
        dt.Columns.Add("intColourID")
        dt.Columns.Add("strName")
        dt.Rows.Add({1, "Red"})
        dt.Rows.Add({2, "Green"})
        dt.Rows.Add({3, "Blue"})

        ListControl1.ValueMember = dt.Columns(0).ColumnName
        ListControl1.DisplayMember = dt.Columns(1).ColumnName
        If False Then
            ListControl1.DataSource = dt
        Else
            For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                ListControl1.Items.Add(dt.Rows(i)("strName").ToString)
            Next
        End If
        ListControl1.SelectedIndex = 2
        Dim z As Form = New Form
        ListControl1.Parent = z
        z.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Do you work for Microsoft? They think they know what I want to do or ought to do better than I do too.

Comment: I can reformulate the issue so that no change of parent is needed. Comment out the first .parent = line, and the last three lines (dim z as form etc). Why does the data-bound list throw an error when the selectedindex is set and the manual one doesn't?

Comment: May be it does not make sense, but does changing the parent make sense? (replaces and corrects my previous comment)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of adding a control to a form is not to set its parent, but to add it to the `Controls` collection of the form. If I do it like this I do not get an exception (the three last lines commented out as you write in your comment).

```
Me.Controls.Add(ListControl1)   ' Instead of ListControl1.Parent = Me
```

Comment: Thank for the suggestion. I thought the two statements were equivalent but that was just an assumption. There still appears to be an issue though - if you comment out the  first .parent = line (not replace it with me.controls.add), there is still an error when setting the selectedindex of the databound list, but not the "manual" list. Why does the list have to be a member of the Controls collection of a form in order for selectedindex to work for a databound list, but not for a manually-populated list?

Comment: In the debugger I saw that the `Items` collection of the `ListBox` was not populated, when using a databound list with a `ListBox` not attached to a form. I do not know why; it's just the way it is implemented. The world is not perfect.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that. Appreciate your time. Now I know what a Listbox does and doesn't do in these circumstances, I will code accordingly.